# Sum two counts in a new column without repeating the code

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have one maybe stupid question.
Look at the query :

```
select count(a) as A, count(b) as b, count(a)+count(b) as C
From X
```

How can I sum up the two columns without repeating the code:
Something like:

```
select count(a) as A, count(b) as b, A+B as C
From X
```

Comment: Repeat the code, use a subquery, or use a CTE.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, using a [CTE](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php):

```
WITH V AS (
  SELECT COUNT(a) as A, COUNT(b) as B
  FROM X
)

SELECT A, B, A + B as C
FROM V
```

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be handled by making the engine perform only two aggregate functions and a scalar computation. Try this.

```
SELECT A, B, A + B as C
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(a) as A, COUNT(b) as B
    FROM X
    ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get the two individual counts of a same table and then get the summation of those counts, like bellow

```
SELECT
   (SELECT COUNT(a) FROM X )+
   (SELECT COUNT(b) FROM X )
AS C
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that, my first code is like that, I sum up the first columns, but the code is repeating. I wanted to know if I can avoid that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Let's agree on one point: SQL is not an Object-Oriented language. In fact, when we think of computer languages, we are thinking of procedural languages (you use the language to describe step by step how you want the data to be manipulated). SQL is declarative (you describe the desired result and the system works out how to get it).

When you program in a procedural languages your main concerns are: 1) *is this the best algorithm to arrive at the correct result*? and 2) *do these steps correctly implement the algorithm*?

When you program in a declarative language your main concern is: *is this the best description of the desired result*?

In SQL, most of your effort will be going into correctly forming the filtering criteria (the `where` clause) and the join criteria (any `on` clauses). Once that is done correctly, you're pretty much just down to aggregating and formating (if applicable).

The first query you show is perfectly formed. You want the number of all the non-null values in A, the number of all the non-null values in B, and the total of both of those amounts. In some systems, you can even use the second form you show, which does nothing more than abstract away the `count(x)` text. This is convenient in that if you should have to change a `count(x)` to `sum(x)`, you only have to make a change in one place rather than two, but it doesn't change the description of the data -- and that is important.

Using a CTE or nested query may allow you to mimic the abstraction not available in some systems, but be careful making cosmetic changes -- changes that do not alter the description of the data. If you look at the execution plan of the two queries as you show them, the CTE and the subquery, in most systems they will probably all be identical. In other words, you've painted your car a different color, but it's still the same car.

But since it now takes you two distinct steps in 4 or 5 lines to explain what it originally took only one step in one line to express, it's rather difficult to defend the notion that you have made an improvement. In fact, I'll bet you can come up with a lot more bullet points explaining why it would be better if you had started with the CTE or subquery and should change them to your original query than the other way around.

I'm not saying that what you are doing is *wrong*. But in the real world, we are generally short of the spare time to spend on strictly cosmetic changes.